# Why label.equals(label1) code doesn't sees label1?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, equals, jtextfield

what is wrong with my code? I'm taking input from JTextField passwordField/nickNameField to fieldNickname/fieldPassword and using for my registerAction. I've searched for answer but cant find.

My code takes input for nickname and password then asks for nickname and password. If true asks for nickname and password again on Login section.

I know problem source but idk what to do. That code must work without problem..

Problem source:

```
else if (trueNickname.equals(fieldNickname) && truePassword.equals(fieldPassword))
```

My code(Register section):

```
JLabel trueNickname = new JLabel("null");
JLabel truePassword = new JLabel("null");
JLabel fieldNickname = new JLabel (nickNameField.getText());
JLabel fieldPassword = new JLabel (passwordField.getText());

public void registerAction(ActionEvent e){
if (a == 0) {
    trueNickname.setText(nickNameField.getText());
    truePassword.setText(passwordField.getText());
    result.setText("Write your Nickname and Password again.");
    a = a + 1;
}
else if (trueNickname.equals(fieldNickname) && truePassword.equals(fieldPassword)) {
    result.setText("True Nickname and Password. You can login.");
}
else if (a == 1) {
    result.setText("SKIPPED(a = 1)");
}

}
```

On launch and using code, I'm getting "SKIPPED" as result.

Note: I'm new in stackoverflow so, sorry if i do something wrong.

Comment: You're comparing _the labels themselves_, not any kind of text inside them.

Comment: Why are you checking if one JLabel equals another? This question and code confuses me. Wouldn't you want to compare the text that they hold instead?

Comment: I'm getting this error "'equals' between objects of inconvertible types 'JLabel' and 'String' " if i try to take dirrectly

Comment: And label havent constant text. Its changes with input

Comment: *'equals' between objects of inconvertible types 'JLabel' and 'String* - I'm sorry but isn't the message clear? How can you compare a JLabel and a String? They are different objects. You need to get the text of the label and compare that to a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the text on the labels, you want to do `trueNickname.getText().equals(fieldNickname.getText())`.

The `equals` method is a common pitfall because it takes an `Object` as a parameter. So the compiler lets you compare any objects even if it's a nonsensical comparison.

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks i got it. I'm new in java, thanks for help.